# How do I disable the overselection of text in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, text-editing

Is there a way to disable the overselection of text in Windows 7? Specifically, when I double-click a word Windows will select the word, then any whitespace after it.

```
word1 word2 word3 wordetc
```

If I were to double-click "word1" I would end up with "word1 " as my selection, when all I want is "word1".

Here are some screengrabs:

[image: Overselection in Sticky Notes]
[image: Overselection in Notepad]
[image: OVerselection in Word 2010]
[image: Overselection in Internet Explorer]